# need help with redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create an web application that will link up a student's facebook, twitter and orkut accounts all under one shed. Its like connecting all the students within a college, to login into the web app, the userid will be the unique studentID provided by the college
itself.

Now, once a student has logged-in, he can open his facebook, twitter and orkut a/c in the same window, lets say under tabs. How can i do that??

I mean how can i pass a student's Facebook's user-id and password to facebook server and if user authentication is done, then show the student his facebook wall.

I am very confused and don't know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing username and passwords is not a  very good idea. Neither Facebook [nor twitter](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/08/twitter-applications-and-oauth.html) supports it through API.

1. For Facebook integration use the [OpenGraph protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph) with any SDK that Facebook provides, like [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). [Mogli](http://github.com/mmangino/mogli) is a ruby wrapper for OpenGraph API
2. For Twitter, there are multiple options like [John Nunemaker's Twitter gem](http://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter). Use that to talk to Twitter API.

Ultimately, it comes down to the architecture of your application. You can start by creating models like '`FacebookConnection`' or '`TwitterConnection`' and linking them to your '`User`' model.

Comment: Open graph protocol does something else, what i want to do is different or may be i missed something. Help me with this, i am new to all of this. How can i use Facebook api to do what i want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Solving it easy, just make the link open twitter/facebook. if they are signed in there already, their homepage will show, otherwise they will be prompted to enter user/pass.

To integrate your application with those platform, each platform got it's API and connect method, with this you won't need the user password be stored in your app. You instead will, twitter as an example, create a twitter application that communicate with twitter's API, and then redirect the user to twitter asking twitter to grant your application some access to the signed in user account, almost the same as you will sign in with your google account here on stackoverflow.

To do the communication with each of those platform, refer to the API/Connect documentation they provide and implement it in your web application. Don't reinvent the wheel, most of the communication functionality will be already coded in an easy to use library, whether for `rubyonrails` or most other development frameworks/languages.

Comment: thanks for the above info. I searched for facebook api, tried to explore but couldn't get a way to solve my problem. Can you help a little in this?

Answer (score 0):

1. look at facebook connect, oath (for twitter) etc instead of storing passwords
2. divs/iframes with some kind of tab control (jQuery?) to handle toggling of what should be visible.

Comment: Facebook Connect is deprecated in favour of Open Graph protocol.